# $params in business rules

Tags: php, yii, business-rules, rbac

Does business rules `$params` use current class attributes as it's indicators?
I met below code in a class and there was no initialization before it for `$param`. `project` is an attribute in this class. How does `$params["project"]` works?

```
class ProjectUserForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $project;
    // .....
    public function assign(){
    // ....
    $bizRule='return isset($params["project"]) && $params["project"]->isUserInRole("owner");';
    // ....
}
```

***EDIT:***
Sorry I know it's dizzy. I try to make it clear.
here is class link [Class](https://gist.github.com/jeffwinesett/3779690)

My problem is **$params**.
I think somewhere before $bizRul initialize we should have something similar to:

```
$params=array('project'=>$project);
```

but we don't have. how this is possible?
Is $params an alias or something like this or we can use any name instead of it?

Comment: Can you please clarify/elaborate further on this. If it's hard to understand then it's hard to help as well.

Comment: you right. I tried to fix it.

Comment: You may also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18300216/291573

Answer (score 0):

You should read this : [Using business rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#using-business-rules).

> A business rule is a piece of PHP code that is executed when we perform access checking.

`$params` can be supplied using [`chekAccess`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#checkAccess-detail), or when you declare your access rules in your controllers.